# Is it safe to set password in /etc/passwd to * on Linux to prevent password login?

Tags: linux, passwd

AFAIK, the second field of /etc/passwd can be

- x: password is in shadow
- hashed password

What if I put a string less than 8 chars in the field? I do not want anyone to use password on this account.

Comment: And why not `passwd -l`?

Comment: @Panki I still want the account to be usable, like ssh with cert.

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly? Only disable a user from logging in via SSH with a password? Or do you want this for _all_ users? The password might be important so the user can use `sudo`.

Comment: @Panki Disable the password usage of the account. Anything that requires its password.

Comment: What Unix are you running?

Comment: @Kusalananda Linux, actually. I am not sure if this makes difference?

Comment: Using a single `*` in the password field is the correct way to prevent authentication on OpenBSD (for example).  You should probably just read the `passwd(5)` manual (`man 5 passwd`).

Comment: @Kusalananda I see. There is no such statement in Linux (at least my desktop), so it may sure make things different. Let me change the Subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If `/etc/shadow` exists, you should not be using the password hash field of the `/etc/passwd` file. You should use the equivalent field in `/etc/shadow` instead.

If you put an invalid string in the password hash field (whether the field that is in active use is in `/etc/shadow` or in `/etc/passwd`), password authentication will be disabled. However, putting in a string of non-standard length would be unexpected: I think it's better to use a character that is not used by the password hashing function. A non-standard-length password hash string might be assumed to be a copy/paste error in mass-editing the password file, but using a character that is outside the standard set is clearly deliberate.

You should also know that the meaning of `passwd -l` was changed.

Before August 2008, the `passwd -l <username>` command was commonly equivalent of this:

```
OLDPW="$(grep ^<username>: /etc/shadow | cut -d : -f 2)"
echo "<username>:!$OLDPW" | chpasswd -e
usermod --expiredate 1 <username>
```

In particular, the `passwd` command in the `shadow` source code package did exactly this.

[On August 22, the command was changed from "locking the account" to "locking the password only".](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/commit/1355d5d3eb6855513a7792846e7526f5307d40dc#diff-7f95a9d50d0f57882117f34139a8609b) In other words, after the change the command now did only the equivalent of this:

```
OLDPW="$(grep ^<username>: /etc/shadow | cut -d : -f 2)"
echo "<username>:!$OLDPW" | chpasswd -e
```

So it still prefixed the encrypted password with an exclamation mark as before, but no longer also marked the entire account as disabled.

The `shadow` source code package was/is the upstream source of many distributions' `passwd` commands, and so the change ended up happening in many distributions. For example, RHEL 5 has the old behavior, but RHEL 6 follows the new one.

Busybox's `passwd` command has a separate codebase, so I have no idea which behavior they're following. [A quick search through BusyBox's documentation](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) seems to indicate it does not include password/account aging functionality at all.

But if you find that running `passwd -l <username>` also disables SSH key authentication for that user (i.e. the old behavior), you can instead lock the password only by setting it to any value that cannot be produced by the password hashing function. For example, like this:

```
echo "username:!" | chpasswd -e
```

This should be a pretty universal way to set an user account to a "non-password-based authentication only" state.

A relatively common convention seems to be to use an exclamation mark (either alone or prefixed to any previous contents of the password hash field) to indicate a locked password, and an asterisk (replacing the entire contents of the password hash field) to mark the account as a system account that is not supposed to be unlockable with `passwd -u`. However, other authentication mechanisms, like SSH keys, can function even if the password hash field has an invalid value.

Comment: Thanks. But seems like the "redefine" has not spreaded to distros using busybox.

Comment: This looks distribution specific.  I can confirm on Debian (Buster) `passwd -l` does prepend a `!` before before the hashed password in `/etc/shadow`.  The result is honored by SSH; even where SSH is using public keys and not passwords and / or PAM, the account is locked.  Therefore (at least on Debian) `password -l` does do more than simply lock password authentication.

Comment: Though ironically, even the debian man page for `passwd` suggests public keys with SSH might still be allowed. I guess the authors can't speak for the authors of SSH.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: I just tested on Debian Stretch, and `passwd -l` does **not** disable SSH key authentication there. The intent of the change to `shadow` suite's `passwd -l` was to specifically create an intuitive way to create accounts that support only non-password-based authentication methods. Does Buster's `passwd -l` modify the account expiration field (= the one before the last colon) in `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: Quoting from the manual `man passwd` ... `This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value (it
           adds a '!' at the beginning of the password).`  Tests confirm that's exactly what it does.  After this `/var/log/auth.log` records `sshd[7786]: User rodger not allowed because account is locked`

Comment: This looks like expected behaviour. See here: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9b61130fbd95d196bce81ebeca94a4cb7c0d5ba0/auth.c#L143 and then here https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9b61130fbd95d196bce81ebeca94a4cb7c0d5ba0/configure.ac#L790

Comment: Putting it simply, yes passwd's behaviour changed, but not all software respects this definition of `!` in the password field.  Some software will still use it to infer the whole account is locked.  Note I have UsePAM set to `no` in `/etc/sshd_config`

Comment: There's one more complication. [This line you mentioned](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9b61130fbd95d196bce81ebeca94a4cb7c0d5ba0/auth.c#L143) can only be reached [if the sshd option UsePAM is disabled](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9b61130fbd95d196bce81ebeca94a4cb7c0d5ba0/auth.c#L135). So, if your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` includes `UsePAM yes`, it *may* be possible to create key-authentication-only accounts with `passwd -l`, but systems with `UsePAM no` will need to find another way.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.  The point being that `passwd` has no control over the way `/etc/shadow` is interpreted by other software with access to it.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood (insufficient caffeination?) and I agree with you.